# how do i send the right kind of object or array to a curl function

Tags: php, arrays, curl

I know ZERO about cURL, this is all Greek to me and my PHP skills are limited. Im relying on the skill of others to make my life easier and its incredibly frustrating when things don't work the way they are supposed to.

Lets start with my input:

```
 $j_source = '{"accountIndex":' . $wallet_idx . ',"walletId": "'. $wallet_id . '"}'; 
    $j_destination = '{"address":"' . $banker . '","amount":' . $lovelace . '}';

    $source         = json_decode($j_source, true); 
    $destination    = json_decode($j_destination, true);
```

Ive got 2 vars that are arrays of JSON. The function wants input as arrays, so thats what im trying to give it.

Function in question ([from here originally](https://github.com/zech001/Cardano-Api-PHP-Wrapper)):

```
// Generates a new transaction from the source to one or multiple target addresses.
    public function createNewTransaction(array $source, array $destination, string $spendingPassword): array
    {
        $groupPolicy = 'OptimizeForHighThroughput';
        return self::jsonDecode($this->post('/api/v1/transactions?source='.$source.'?destination='.$destination.'?groupingPolicy='.$groupPolicy.'?spendingPassword='.$spendingPassword), true);
    }
```

When I run this function the results are an error:

> Array ( [status] => error [diagnostic] => Array ( [validationError] =>
>   Error in $: When parsing the constructor Payment of type
>   Cardano.Wallet.API.V1.Types.Payment expected Object but got Array. )
>   [message] => JSONValidationFailed )

So then, obviously I tried to send it an array as an object, with an error, telling me that it wants an object not an array. So now Im going in circles and I don't know what to do next.

This is the cURL POST function im using:

```
// CURL Post
    private function post(string $endPoint, $postFields = []): string
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->host.$endPoint);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, $this->port);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postFields));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, Cardano::CERT_PATH);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');

        $headers = [
            "Cache-Control: no-cache",
            "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8",
            "Postman-Token: b71b609e-e028-d78b-ce51-3d0ec0b5c9fb",
            "accept: application/json;charset=utf-8"        
        ];
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        if($this->disableSSLVerification)
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        }
        $data = curl_exec ($ch);
        $this->httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
        {
            throw new Exception('Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }
        curl_close ($ch);
        return $data;
    }
```

As far as I can tell, this CURL code was automatically generated using something called "Postman" (I downloaded it, but I don't understand how to use it, so not helpful at all).

The problem is this, I don't know whats wrong. I don't know if its a problem with the way the CURL is constructed, I don't know if its a problem in the class that contains the createNewTransaction function.

What I do know is that the GET functions in the library work without issue. I can run GET queries and get valid JSON back without a problem.

If you could could give me some hints or clues about whats wrong I can probably figure it out on my own, I just dont know where to even start.

Comment: there's plenty of wrong here, $j_source and $j_destination is incorrectly encoded (for example, what happens if $banker has a " in the name? json_decode will fail and return NULL, and whatever tries to read the members of $destination will crash php with an exception), any and all potential errors of curl_setopt is silently ignored. but the actual immidate problem here seems to be that something is wrong with the return of json_encode($postFields) in function `post`

Comment: you know, im really not worried about the details right now, im mostly concerned about just getting it to work. the details mean nothing, if nothing works. i would appreciate more help and less commentary. thank.

Comment: .. and what does json_encode($postFields) return in the post function when you get that error?